# how to improve response time for my bot after changing from MemoryStorage to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, performance, azure, botframework, azure-blob-storage

The change of the storage provider for my bot led to significant delays in response time - and sometimes there is not any repsonse at all -

before: Memory Storage - excellent response time

after: Azure blob storage - rather bad performance

Memory Storage for bots should only be used for non-PROD setups - at least when moving to QA or PROD developers should either switch to "Blob" or CosmosDB - if the bot code have been taken from examples or generated by yeoman generator then there is usually some inline comment as a reminder developers.

I'm using SDK V4 - recent bot code from 2019 - using nodeJS -

before:

```
const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);
```

after:

```
const { BlobStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');
const STORAGE_CONFIGURATION_ID = "myblogstorage";
// Get service configuration
const blobStorageConfig = botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(STORAGE_CONFIGURATION_ID);
const blobStorage = new BlobStorage({
     containerName: (blobStorageConfig.container || DEFAULT_BOT_CONTAINER),
     storageAccountOrConnectionString: blobStorageConfig.connectionString,
 });

conversationState = new ConversationState(blobStorage);
userState = new UserState(blobStorage);
```

I expected some obvious delay from memory to calling a remote service - but I'm afraid that a delay so significant is hardly acceptable.

1.) Is it just me - or did others found the same issue ?

2.) Is there anything else I need to consider in order to get this fixed - e.g. change to a certain storage service class which can open and react faster (which?) - or making functions 'async'
which are still blocking (which, any best-practice?) - or "preheat" / prepare the connection earlier in case in order to avoid the handshaking during the course of the dialog - something like this ?

I found some performance complaints about directline / botframework back in 2017 - but assume that these are not valid any more - directline was fast enough with MemoryStorage

Comment: Why can't you use memory storage in production?

Comment: @Soviut, using in-memory is NOT recommended for a production environment. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#memory-storage) for more information regarding using memory storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the botbuilder community on GitHub, they've got excellent resources to help you understand your options around state management.
[This example](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/ff608ff789b22c7539fde57c0b4d5a8f36de6b84/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework/README.md) shows how to use Elasticstorage as your ConversationState provider.  There may be a custom implementation that you can roll, too.

Comment: thanks, @Irwin - I guess that is it - I found an issue and asked what works for others who came to this point - then go to the community place seems to be the best option

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you move away from blog storage. While it is a provided option for storage service, it is not as scalable as some other services. Cosmos provides better scalability via adjustments to throughput, etc., for example. However, pricing is a factor for most people.

It's important to note that you can connect to and store your data via any medium you desire. The Bot Framework Team provides information for connecting your bot to Cosmos and Blob storage but you are not limited to just those options. You *will* need to figure you the configuration between your bot and whichever service you decide to land on. As an example, this (non-MS) GitHub [repo](https://github.com/botbuilder-contrib/botbuilder-storage-mongodb) demonstrates how to utilize Mongo as the data storage layer. I haven't personally tested it, but it's worth looking over.

Hope of help!

Comment: thx @Steven Kanberg for the quick reply - however, I still would like to keep this question open for the following reason: I got a number of options for further research but I still miss some guidance which storage provider to choose when - kind of decision matrix - devs need a persistant storage - which was Azure tables when I started, which is no longer officially supported, hm? However, there is community package - then there is official blob storage which is not recommended - and there are even more solutions (your mentioned Mongo) - anyone else to share experiece what works for him/her ?